# Rotate Cursor in button click event c#

Tags: c#, cursor

I want to start rotation of cursor constantly on button1_click and  to stop that rotation on button2_click

My cursor is :
[image]

My output is :
[image]

I want to rotate this one cursor on start button click and to stop that rotation on stop button click event

here is my code : But I have taken static 4 cursor to roate which is not correct..
still this is my code:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.Cursor = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath + "\\1.cur");            
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string fileName);
    Cursor myCursor;
    int a;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle1 = LoadCursorFromFile("E:/Cursor_Rotate/WindowsFormsApplication5/WindowsFormsApplication5/1.cur");
        IntPtr handle2 = LoadCursorFromFile("E:/Cursor_Rotate/WindowsFormsApplication5/WindowsFormsApplication5/2.cur");
        IntPtr handle3 = LoadCursorFromFile("E:/Cursor_Rotate/WindowsFormsApplication5/WindowsFormsApplication5/3.cur");
        IntPtr handle4 = LoadCursorFromFile("E:/Cursor_Rotate/WindowsFormsApplication5/WindowsFormsApplication5/4.cur");
        myCursor = new Cursor(handle1);
        this.Cursor = myCursor;
        a = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        myCursor = new Cursor(handle2);
        this.Cursor = myCursor;
        a = 2;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        myCursor = new Cursor(handle3);
        this.Cursor = myCursor;
        a = 3;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        myCursor = new Cursor(handle4);
        this.Cursor = myCursor;
        a = 4;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: Oh, Thread.Sleep is really bad idea for button click. I think add some timer  which triggers cursor rotate will be much better idea

Comment: can you explain your idea in brief or by code?

Comment: @Ammy look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ammy With Thread.Sleep will 'freeze' your UI after start button click

Comment: Yea I know this code is totally wrong..but as I dont know any another option thats y used this code...